# Why customers ask does your managed package contains any lightning components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, managed-package

I have seen many customers asking whether your app contains the lightning components. Does this has any impact on the app purchase?

In my managed package, all our visualforce pages are being used with `SLDS` and it looks exactly like the Lightning.

List few benefits of using lightning components in Managed package?

Your help is most appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Lightning is the future and has much better UI. And also future is here!

Reusable lightning components are quite powerful for ISVs and customers, as it helps admins to easily customize the whole application in a highly flexible way.

With SLDS stylesheets in Visualforce, you are not really utilizing full potential of Lightning; unless you start using Lightning components it won't really be lightning and just look like it.

Note that Visualforce has some overhead of view state, hence it is a bit heaving and slow; whereas components are faster and can be easily customizable using app builder.

Some more documentation for reference-

- [Welcome to the Future of CRM. Welcome to Salesforce Lightning.](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2015/08/future-of-crm-salesforce-lightning.html)
- [10 Reasons to Switch On Salesforce Lightning](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2016/08/10-reasons-to-switch-on-salesforce-lightning.html)
- [Lightning FAQ](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_FAQ)
- [Compare Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_aloha_comparison.htm&type=5)